# Cell referencing using just numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula:

```
=LET(Data,'Sheet1'!G9:Y19, .....)
```

I really would like to reference `Y19` using numbers, kind of like

```
=LET(Data,'Sheet1'!G9:Column(25)19, .....)
```

if that makes sense. Since this cell reference changes and needs to be dynamic. How can I achieve this? Could I just remake a formula in VBA that does this? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `INDEX`:

```
=LET(Data,'Sheet1'!G9:INDEX(Sheet1!1:1048576,19,25)...
```